# Do I have to write hundreds of switch-case-statements in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a `list` with hundreds of items and I need to call `myFunction()` with one of those items. The parameter depends from another variable `value`. So I came up with something like this:

```
let list = [1, 2, 3, ...]
switch(value) {
   case list[0]
      myFunction(value);
   break;
   case list[1]
      myFunction(value);
   break;
   case list...
}
```

Do I have to write hundreds of `case` statements or is there a better way?

Comment: wait, do you put different logic for each item? or same logic but different calculation?

Comment: What is it you're testing really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your functions in the list :

```js
const functions = [a, b, c, d];

function a() { return "A"; }
function b() { return "B"; }
function c() { return "C"; }
function d() { return "D"; }

document.write(functions[0]());
```

Still the same if you have arguments :

```js
const functions = [a, b, c, d];

function a(value) { return "A "+value; }
function b(value) { return "B "+value; }
function c(value) { return "C "+value; }
function d(value) { return "D "+value; }

document.write(functions[0]("myValue"));
```

But you have to ensure all functions have the same signature (parameters count, types, ...) or it will become a mess quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let list = [1, 2, 3, ...]
switch(value) {
   case list[0]
      myFunction(value);
   break;
   case list[1]
      myFunction(value);
   break;
   case list...
}
```

If "value" equals the list item, why not call myFunction(value) directly? If you need to verify value is in the array, you could use

```
if (list.includes(value)) {
  myFunction(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will switch to another approach. I committed a fallacy.